# Laravel webpack doesn't watch css files

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

This is my webpack.mix.js file:

```
 let mix = require('laravel-mix');

 mix.js(['resources/assets/admin/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/admin/js/core/app.js',
    'resources/assets/admin/js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/assets/admin/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js',
    ], 'public/assets/admin/js/all.js')
.styles(['resources/assets/admin/css/bootstrap.css',
        'resources/assets/admin/css/core.css',
        'resources/assets/admin/css/components.css',
        'resources/assets/admin/css/custom-style.css',
        'resources/assets/admin/css/colors.css',
        'resources/assets/admin/css/icons/fontawesome/styles.min.css',
        'resources/assets/admin/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css',
   ],
   'public/assets/admin/css/all.css').sourceMaps();
```

I run **nmp run watch** command and when I edit any js files it recompiles immediately but when I edit css files nothing happens! how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `scripts()` and `styles()` are being run in background when you run `npm run watch`. But `laravel-mix` does not notify about that on terminal.

You can find discussion about this issue here on [`laravel-mix` project](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/656#issuecomment-293365242) from Owner.

May be solution for your issue would be updating the `laravel-mix` version and check if workaround is implemented for this issue.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Yes, you're right laravel-mix dosn't show any notifications for css files on terminal unlike javascript files but it applies the changes. Thank you so much.